# Starting thin server on Raspberry PI on startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, debian, raspberry-pi

I want to start the [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) web server upon restart of my Raspberry Pi.

I have the required config file in `/etc/thin/myapp.yml`

```
---
chdir: "/home/pi/web-interface/current"
environment: production
address: 0.0.0.0
port: 3000
timeout: 30
log: "/home/pi/web-interface/shared/tmp/sockets/log/thin.log"
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 100
require: []
wait: 30
threadpool_size: 20
servers: 1
daemonize: true
```

I did this to install thin as a runlevel command:

```
thin install
sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f thin defaults
```

From the second command I get the following Log output

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match thin Default-Stop values (S 0 1 6)
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 6) of script `thin' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6 S).
```

When I run `/etc/init.d/thin start` the server starts without trouble so there seems to be something wrong when the device starts up.

This is `/etc/init.d/thin`:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          thin
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      S 0 1 6
# Short-Description: thin initscript
# Description:       thin
### END INIT INFO

# Original author: Forrest Robertson

# Do NOT "set -e"

# DAEMON=/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/thin
DAEMON=/home/pi/.rvm/wrappers/raspberrypi/thin
SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/init.d/thin
CONFIG_PATH=/etc/thin

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
        say "Starting thin"
    $DAEMON start --all $CONFIG_PATH
    ;;
  stop)
        say "Stopping thin"
    $DAEMON stop --all $CONFIG_PATH
    ;;
  restart)
    $DAEMON restart --all $CONFIG_PATH
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

Now my server does not startup up properly even though I have the following entry in my boot log:

```
Sat Mar  1 08:19:45 2014: [start] /etc/thin/myapp.yml ...
Sat Mar  1 08:19:52 2014: [....] Starting NTP server: ntpd^[[?25l^[[?1c^[7^[[1G[^[[32m ok ^[[39;49m^[8^[[?25h^[[?0c.
Sat Mar  1 08:19:54 2014: [....] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd^[[?25l^[[?1c^[7^[[1G[^[[32m ok ^[[39;49m^[8^[[?25h^[[?0c.
Sat Mar  1 08:19:56 2014: Starting server on 0.0.0.0:3000 ... 
Sat Mar  1 08:19:56 2014:
```

Comment: Did you consider to use nginx + passenger instead? See https://github.com/meinside/rails-on-raspberrypi or http://brianmilco.blogspot.de/2013/02/chiliproject-nginx-and-passenger-on.html#!/2013/02/chiliproject-nginx-and-passenger-on.html as starter...

Comment: Why would you opt for this option. I like thin for the fact that it integrates well with rails when developing. Just add the gem to the Gemfile and start the server as normal: `rails s`.

Comment: No doubt, it is nice for development. However, is seemd for me you try to have you RPi booting with running web server, serving an application. This sounds like production to me, which should use a more performant server... Of course, thin might be enough for personal use.

Comment: @theldoria I think you are right that thin might not be ideal here. However, I am using the RasPi at home so "production" is a bit relative here too. I might try out passenger later on, for now I want to manage to run it with thin though.

Comment: Have you already run the servier manually successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the S from this line:

```
# Default-Stop:      S 0 1 6
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something called crontab. Maybe it can help you, to start it when your raspberry starts.